# Prevent PC from sleeping while running Photoshop batch

Tags: windows-10, batch, sleep, adobe-photoshop

I'm running Windows 10 and latest version of Photoshop CC. I started a long running batch and I assumed Photoshop would keep the computer awake, but apparently it doesn't.

Is there a setting in Photoshop to prevent sleep? Do I need to change my power options every time I have a long running batch?